# Temporarily remove event listener and then add it right back after certain actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a react app with a div that is scrollable.
e.g.

```
<main id="main" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
```

How do I temporarily remove the onScroll event listener from main?
and then add it right back after doing certain actions?

I have two ways of getting access to the element

```
document.getElementById('main')
```

and

```
$('#main')
```

I have tried to inspect the element returned but I don't seems to find the onScroll property where this.handleScroll has been attached.
I would like to temporarily remove it and add it right back if it is possible.

I am trying to create a scrollSpy effect.
In my navbar I set the section I and then scroll the div with id `'main'`. However since I use the onScroll event listener on main to also detect what is on screen to detect the section activated, this is causing some conflict.  Therefore I need to temporarily suspend the event listener while doing things in the navbar.

Comment: The most straightforward way would  be to check some condition or put the scroll behavior in an intermediate function

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate real actual user scrolling vs a scroll caused by containerElement.scrollTop = X ?

Comment: I would think not. Just do like `programmaticScrolling = true; containerElement.scrollTop = x; programmaticScrolling = false;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with jQuery or without jQuery.

You can create a function that can be reused to remove the listeners:

```
// To add listener.
$('#main').addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll); // jQuery
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll); // Without jQuery

// To remove listener.
$('#main').removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll); // Remove listener with jQuery
document.getElementById('main').removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll); // Remove listener without jQuery.
```

You can add or remove the listener where ever you want with this.

Comment: Anyway to listen to scroll stop?